# java to mongoDB Date in where clause

Tags: java, mongodb, date

I am trying to compare a date from java to mongoDB as follows. But it does not working correctly.

**Java code:**

```
Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
               calendar1.setTime(new java.util.Date());
                calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 00);
                calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
                calendar1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
                calendar1.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 000);
                Date a1 = new Date();
                a1 = calendar.getTime();

MongoDatabase database = mongo.getDatabase("dummy");
        MongoCollection<Document> dbCollection= database.getCollection("something");
        long count = dbCollection.count(Filters.and(Filters.gte("startTime", a1)));
```

**Mongo DB Collection**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("586cd802de77f23f"),
    "name" : "sim",
    "serverity" : "high",
    "startTime" : ISODate("2017-01-04T11:11:32.058Z")
}
```

Comment: Use new Date(a1) in the comparison, Filters.gte("startTime", a1), you use new Date(a1)

Comment: the problem of using that is, i need to get start time (midnight) of the a1 and endtime (midnight) also. so new Date(a1) not used.

Comment: Use a1 = calendar1.getTime();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a mistake here,

instead of using

```
a1 = calendar1.getTime();
```

i used

```
a1 = calendar.getTime();
```

hence it is taking `Wed Jan 04 23:55:55 IST 2017` so the code was not working.

The above code is working fine.